# Is there a way other than kivy to use python on an android app

Tags: python, android

Lately, I used the cv2 module in python so that when an image is placed the program would print what object is in the image. Now, I'm trying to make this work on an android app where the user can capture a photo and the app would output the object inside that photo. Can someone please please tell me what should be done.

Comment: why can't you use `kivy` for this?

Comment: @Matiiss I'm just trying to find for efficient ways